# Renaming alias references without having to use find/replace

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, alias

By now, everyone should know that Visual Studio has an option to allow you to rename items and auto-fix any references to them.  For example, if I want to change a class named `clsEmployee` to just `Employee`, making the change causes a red underscore to appear beneath the name.  I can then hit `CTRL+.` or click on it to bring up a context menu that will allow me to also fix any references to the old name.

It doesn't seem that I can do this with type aliases, though.  When I change an alias name, I don't have the option to rename all code that references it, so it presents the feel that aliases are not strongly typed.

Is this just "one of those things" or am I not doing something right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: VS2013 does not automatically suggest renaming [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). It does support renaming them if you choose it from the EDIT or context menu, or with the (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) shortcut (hold Ctrl, press R twice, release Ctrl).

[image: Right click > Refactor > Rename (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R)]

Why isn't the support for this better? My guess is that it's because aliases are not a commonly-used feature (usually you just use the full name, or `var`), so something relatively minor like this can be overlooked. Aliases are most useful when you have conflicting type names. I've also used an alias when I have a very long generic type name that I use multiple times in a short file.

Comment: Works great.  Yes, I am using aliases for long generic type declarations, too.  It's a generic list of a generic type.  I'd use `var` if I weren't passing this object as parameters to methods.  At any rate, this does the trick.